# Opening downloaded Gist folder to inspect elements

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, gist

I want to experiment with Mike Bostock's stacked bar chart (https://gist.github.com/3886208) in my browser using web inspector. I realize that I need a local copy of the example files (the index.html and the data.csv file) in order to play with it. However, when I download the 'gist' folder and open the index.html file with Chrome, the chart doesn't appear. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Google Chrome, go to Top Menu > View > Developer > Javascript console. You will see a message

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///path/to/data.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

As per https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

> When developing locally, note that your browser may enforce strict
>   permissions for reading files out of the local file system. If you use
>   d3.xhr locally (including d3.json et al.), you must have a local web
>   server. For example, you can run Python's built-in server:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 &
```

Once this is running, go to `http://localhost:8888/`.